# find items in list1 that are also in list2 and delete items not in list1

Tags: python, list

i want to find items that are in `list1`:

```
list1 = ['peach', 'plum', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'grape']
```

that are also in `list2`:

```
list2 = ['peach,0,1,1,0,1,0,1', 'carrot,1,0,1,1,0,1,1', 'lime,0,1,1,0,1,1,0', 'apple,0,1,1,0,1,1,1']
```

the problem is that the items in `list2` have numbers after the needed item. how do i find the common items in both `list1` and `list2`, and delete the items in `list2` that are not in `list1` (while still keeping the zeros and ones after the overlapping items?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
# using a set makes the later `x in keep` test faster
keep = set(['peach', 'plum', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'grape'])

list2= ['peach,0,1,1,0,1,0,1', 'carrot,1,0,1,1,0,1,1', 
        'lime,0,1,1,0,1,1,0', 'apple,0,1,1,0,1,1,1']

# x.split(',',1)[0] = the part before the first `,` 
new = [x for x in list2 if x.split(',',1)[0] in keep]
```

Comment: Ha! 5 mins spent typing out an answer which basically equals yours. I defer to your superior typing speed :)

Answer (score 0):

Psuedocode:

```
for each i in list1
    foreach j in list2
        if j.contains(i)
            list2.remove(j)
```

Treat j and i as strings, and look to see if each element contains the element from list1.

Comment: It's a bad idea to modify list2 while you are iterating over it

Answer (score 0):

Cédric's answer (which was deleted but was a good inspiration, thanks to him) misses the point that you have a string including all the 0 and the 1. To be complete:

```
for item in list1:
    try:
       list2.remove(item.split(',')[0])
    except ValueError:
      pass
```

Max

Comment: This deletes the items in list2 that *are* in list1, OP wants to delete those that *are not* in list1.

Comment: @Jochen Ritzel: damn, you are right, sorry for answering too fast too. Thanks for your correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may help(note that it will create new list object):

```
list1= ['peach', 'plum', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'grape']
list2= ['peach,0,1,1,0,1,0,1', 'carrot,1,0,1,1,0,1,1', 'lime,0,1,1,0,1,1,0', 'apple,0,1,1,0,1,1,1']
list2 = [x for x in list2 for y in list1 if x.split(',')[0]==y]
```

Comment: This won't work properly if there is a grapefruit or a pineapple in list2